# Where should a Kafka consumer that processes HDFS data run?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka

I am new to Hadoop and Kafka. I inherited code for a Kafka consumer that runs on a desktop Windows machine, receives the HDFS location of new XML data available on a remote cluster, downloads the data for processing, and writes the result back out to the HDFS cluster.

It seems to me that the consumer should run on the cluster because that's where the data is but all the sample Kafka consumer code I see suggests that producer/consumers run on regular desktop machines. What is the typical target platform for Kafka consumer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producers and consumers can run anywhere. The examples you see imply a desktop execution because that code is much simpler than, say, code running within a Storm topology and examples tend to be overly simple.  The only reason for a desktop environment would be the presence of a UI for the application.

If the application is headless, then it does make a lot of sense to move the execution as close to the data (both Kafka and HDFS) as possible.